# conflicting instantiation - memory leak?

Tags: c++, qt, memory, memory-leaks

I've been lurking about these questions for awhile and learned alot but recently have come up against a problem that I don't understand. I'm using Qt and need to create/replace a QMovie object in various class methods (which is ultimately set in a QLabel). I've defined the object using the new keyword. Thus in the header I have

```
QMovie * movie;
```

For simplicity I'll put the equivalent code in a single method. This is equivalent to the two lines of code

```
QMovie * movie = new QMovie(QByteArray1,this);
QMovie * movie = new QMovie(QByteArray2,this);
```

This works (I don't know why) but since it is a repeated operation I worry about memory leaks. It appears that the second definition replaces the first one successfully but since presumably they each have diffeent pointers I don't know how to delete the pointer to the first definition. I delete movie in the class destructor but don't know if it will delete everything. Anyone know what is happening here?

P.S. I do this because the only way (I've found in  Qt) to create a QMovie object using data in a QByteArray (which was downloaded from the web) is to use the QMovie constructor. If I just wanted to replace the current movie data with new data from a file I could use the method

```
movie->setFileName(fileName);
```

but this isn't an option when using binary data. Note: QMovie also has a constructor that has a filename instead of a QByteArray as an argument. Using filenames also works using the above code and is easier to test.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The constructor in your example does not seem to match any in QMovie. Which one is it? http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qmovie.html#QMovie

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, if anything derived from `QObject` is contained in a hierarchy of `QObject`s, they are automatically destructed when the parent is destructed.  In your case, you are giving the `QMovie` a parent through the constructor, so the cleanup should be taken care of for you.  If you want to confirm, derive a class from QMovie, implement a destructor that prints a message, and make sure it is called when you expect (i.e. when the parent is destructed).

Comment: This cleanup will occur only when the parent `QObject` gets destructed. This may cause what is in effect a memory leak, but is hideously hard to find since all memory leak detector tools will correctly notice that eventually the objects got freed. QObject's memory management is not a cure-all. It needs some understanding to leverage. Its major benefits are when the lifetime of child objects approximates the lifetime of the parent object. If the children have useful life spans that are much shorter, you need a different solution to relinquish memory on top of parent-child relationships.

Comment: @KubaOber Calling that a "memory leak" is sketchy at best. There are ways to ensure the object is destructed before the parent is destructed - including just plain old `delete`: the object removes itself from its own parents (see [this documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/objecttrees.html)), even if just a plain pointer is used.

Comment: To me, memory is leaked if an object persists past its useful lifetime. QObject doesn't fix that problem by itself for children that are supposed to live shorter than the parent, just as I said. Invoking QObject in this context is thus pointless. As we all know, the OS will eventually clean it all up when the out-of-memory protection kills the process :)

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic way of doing it in C would be:

1. Initialize the pointer to zero.
2. Before assigning to it, `free()` the object pointed to by the old pointer. You *do not need* to check for zero: `free()` on a zero pointer is a safe no-op.
3. `free()` the object when the pointer goes out of scope.

The idiomatic way of doing it in Qt is even simpler.

1. Use `QSharedPointer<>` or `QScopedPointer<>`. It will automatically delete the pointed-to object when it goes out of scope.

   - If only one pointer is supposed to own the object, use `QScopedPointer`. It will delete the pointed-to object when it goes out of scope. This is similar to `std::auto_ptr`.
   - For shared ownership, use `QSharedPointer`. It will delete the pointed-to object when the last `QSharedPointer` that points to it goes out of scope/gets destroyed.
2. For `QScopedPointer`, use `reset(T*other)` method to assign a new value to the pointer. For `QSharedPointer`, you can only assign other shared pointers to it, like `QSharedPointer a = QSharedPointer(new Class);`

In either case, any previously pointed-to object will be deleted.

Thus:

```
class MyClass {
  QScopedPointer<QMovie> movie1;
  QSharedPointer<QMovie> movie2;
public:
  MyClass {} // note: no need for any special initialization
  void method() {
    movie1.reset(new QMovie(...));
    movie2 = QSharedPointer(new QMovie(...));
  }
};
```

This is completely safe. You can call `MyClass::method()` as often as you wish with no memory leaks. At any point in time, MyClass will keep alive at most two QMovie objects.

Comment: QPointer will never destroy the object being pointed to. The only service it provides is nulling itself upon the destruction of the object that it points to.

Comment: Unfortunately, your answer is misleading. It seems like you're suggesting that QPointer is just an improved version of QScopedPointer for QObjects, when in fact they are nothing alike. Reading your answer again, I suppose you might have implicitly assumed that all QObjects will have parents with a reasonable lifetime, but in my experience this is not true.

Comment: Perhaps the downvoter could speak up as to what's wrong? I've addresses Slavik81's concerns.

Comment: I downvoted. I didn't notice you'd edited because I just glanced at it and saw only the spot you forgot to change: "Use QPointer<> or QScopedPointer<>. It will automatically delete the pointed-to object when it goes out of scope."

Comment: Cool, thanks. I very much like those to be error-free, since folks with less experience can easily get hung up on details being wrong. I know I did, a number of times no less :)

Answer (score 0):

```
QMovie * movie = new QMovie(QByteArray1,this);
QMovie * movie = new QMovie(QByteArray2,this);
```

If these two lines are in the same `.cc` file, then you will get a redefinition error. If the two lines are in separate `.cc` files, then when you build the executable, you will get a multiple definition error. But, your question has this wording:

> I'm using Qt and need to create/replace a QMovie object in various class methods (which is ultimately set in a QLabel)

If the `QMovie` object resides in different classes, you don't have a memory leak, because each class's pointer is different from another's.

However, if your intention is that all the classes refer to the same `QMovie` instance, you will need to find a way to pass the instance to each object. Alternatively, you would have them all refer to the same one (i.e., using the singleton pattern).